# How can I submit just filled inputs of a form in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: html, asp.net-core

I like to know if it possible to submit just filled inputs of a form and show their name and value in url in browser.

Example:

```
<form method="get">
   <input name="firstname" value="a" />
   <input name="lastname" value="" />
</form>
```

I like to show in url as:

```
?firstname=a
```

not as:

```
?firstname=a&lastname=
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can use ajax to pass filled inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use javascript to achieve this result. For example you can make empty inputs `disabled` so browser doesn't send their values

Form

```
<form method="get" id="the-form">
    <input name="firstname" value="a" />
    <input name="lastname" value="" />

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
    let form = document.querySelector('#the-form');
    form.addEventListener('submit', () => {
        let inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input');
        for (let input of inputs) {
            if (!input.value) {
                input.disabled = true;
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```